# Alterar um documento Word através de uma aplicação Asp.Net Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Segue uma dúvida: no cenário atual, temos 10 documentos Word que serão preenchidos com informações oriundas de telas. Qual componente nativo do `.net` ou de terceiros, que realizam essa alteração nos documentos existentes?

Answer (score 0):

Jucinei, acredito que isto pode lhe ajudar:

[Manipulating Word 2007 Files with OpenXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb656295.aspx#Y593)